# Override dataExporter method or realize lazy export in jsf

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-dataexporter

I use `<p:dataExporter type="xls" target="reportTable" fileName="ExportResult"/>` in my project. And i need some functionality.

```html
<p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="currentReportTablesStyle" style="text-align: center">
    <p:commandButton value="Load Data"
                     id="dataLoaderButton"
                     ajax="false"
                     action="#{QCforCCReportBean.LoadReport()}"/>
    <h:outputText value="Export to format:"/>
    <h:commandLink disabled="#{QCforCCReportBean.isNotAdministrator}">
        <p:graphicImage name="/images/xls_file.png" width="24"/>
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="reportTable" fileName="ExportResult"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</p:panelGrid>
```

When i click to commandButton - "Load Data"  for export data, triggered method from `"#{QCforCCReportBean.LoadReport()}"`. This method have two variable in parameters: first and pageSize. I set This variables 0 and 50. It work cool. I have lazy and good pagination. For example 0-50, 50-100, 100 - 150 etc.
But when i tried export data, triggered some method `"#{QCforCCReportBean.LoadReport()}"` but variables is 0- 87587(or another big number. all rows from table) and my java crash with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

I want override method for export data or modify dataExporter save data by parts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout when exporting large dataset as XLSX using p:dataExporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162591/timeout-when-exporting-large-dataset-as-xlsx-using-pdataexporter)

Answer (score 0):

The magnificant [PrimeFaces 5.2 Documentation states on page 132](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf#132) a list of attributes. One of them is:

```
pageOnly    0    String    Exports only current page instead of whole dataset
```

And on page #133 there even is an example:

> ## PageOnly
>
> By default dataExporter works on whole dataset, if you ’ d
>   like export only the data displayed on  current page, set pageOnly to
>   true.
>
> ```
> <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tableId" fileName="cars" pageOnly="true"/>
> ```

Comment: I dont want export visible page, i want export all data but by little pices, becouse if i export all data i get out of memory error.

Comment: So you want to download 100 xlsx files? And then? Manually merge them? Or do 100 queries to the db and serverside add these to the xlsx in blocks? Well, if you want the latter, then just do that. Look at the exporter source code and adapt it to your needs. If you have detailed problems get back with those. The question as it stands now is a 'homework' one

Comment: No, he wants to download one file containing all the data.

Comment: That I already understood. But as long as the op did not investigate what part causes the OoM problem (his backing beans /model or the xlsx), I cannot create a new answer or improve my existing one.

Comment: See the newest documentation. Select the version you need in the url: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/components/dataexporter